# Git ignore a folder except a given file outside the folder

Tags: git

I had the following simple .gitignore file.

```
#  Local .terraform directories. Here .terraform is a folder
**/.terraform/*

# .tfstate files
*.tfstate
*.tfstate.*

# .tfvars files
*.tfvars

# .tfplan files
*.tfplan

# .pem files
*.pem

# .hcl files from Terraform v0.14 and newer
*.hcl

# working directory for web app
/globo_web_app/*

**/next-step.txt
```

Note that this makes git to ignore `.terraform.lock.hcl` file as well.

Also note that `.terraform.lock.hcl` is not inside of .terraform folder. See the shot below.

But Now I learnt that this `.terraform.lock.hcl` file [must be checked into VC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67975490/1977871). So it should not be ignored by git.

I am not able to achieve that.

[image: gitignore file]

I tried adding `!.terraform.lock.hcl` as shown be in the above screen shot. But it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice you still have this line in your `.gitignore`:

```
*.hcl
```

which, as you know, ignores all `.hcl` files. If you've added the `!.terraform.lock.hcl` before that line, it will not work. You need to change it to:

```
*.hcl
!.terraform.lock.hcl
```